# Azure Redis Cache + WordPress On Azure

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I've followed the instructions in this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azureossds/archive/2015/05/14/connect-to-azure-redis-cache-from-wordpress-site.aspx) to configure this but redis status is always showing not connected. I tried to turn on diagnostics on redis cache instance but it doesn't even seem like any requests are getting to the service itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more investigation it looks like there is a thread that covers the majority of the scenarios on the plug in discussions page... I would read through this and ensure you have things in the properly place as well...

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/enabling-with-predis-and-remote-redis

Comment: Also, you should make sure to update to 4.2.2 ASAP as there are some fixes to a major security vulnerability

Comment: Upgraded to 4.2.2 I saw that thread and moving the defines above "/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */" fixes the problem. Interesting that it sees the settings. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: Perhaps you could add this to that blog post :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is not supported by the predis library, you must use the non HTTPS endpoint which is 6379.

Comment: Same result. I noticed the version shown in the screen shot in that blog post and what I'm seeing seems different. Is there any additional steps?

Comment: Unrelated issue - I noticed when you turn on diagnostics on redis cache, I'm able to hit save without having a storage account selected but errors. Saves successfully once I select a storage account

Comment: Can you confirm that the object-cache.php file is indeed in wp-content

Comment: You could also verify that there is indeed nothing making it to cache by using redis-cli to connect to the redis service

Comment: I've verified that wp-content folder has object-cache.php file and also can connect to azure redis from redis-cli

Comment: Azure Redis disables the non-ssl port 6379 by default.  If you are trying to connect to that port, you need to enable it first through the portal.  Port 6380 is the SSL port and is always enabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https for redis cache and wordpress. You need to set it to set WP_REDIS_SCHEME to use TLS. See: https://cloud.accigo.se/blog/how-to-set-up-azure-redis-cache-for-wordpress/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)